# How to infer type from another property

Tags: typescript

I'm typing a basic migration utility – an object that has properties `up()` and `down()`. When committing a migration I'm saving the returned data from the `up()` function and then passing it as an argument to the `down()` function, like this:

```js
const myMigration: Migration<number[]> = {
  async up() {
    return [1, 2, 3];
  },
  async down(data) {
    data.forEach(number => console.log(number)); // 1, 2, 3
  },
};
```

So far, I've defined the Migration type like this:

```js
type Migration<T = void> = {
  up(): Promise<T>
  down(data: T): Promise<void>
}
```

The current problem is that I have to explicitly define the type, but rather I would like to have the type of the `down()` data argument inferred from the awaited return type of `up()`.

Here are some of my failed attempts:

```js
// doesn't work

type Migration<T = void> = {
  up(): Promise<T>
  down<U extends T = T>(data: U): Promise<void>
}
```

```js
// doesn't infer type from the same instance

type Migration<T = void> = {
  up(): Promise<T>
  down(data: Awaited<ReturnType<Migration["up"]>>): Promise<void>
}
```

Desired result:

```js
const myMigration: Migration = {
  async up() {
    return [1, 2, 3];
  },
  async down(data) {
    // yay, type of data is inferred
    data.forEach(number => console.log(number)); // 1, 2, 3
  },
};
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsglgcwE4ENhwPYDsA8AVKAXigDcM4ATAPiKgG8AoKZqAVzAAoBKALigAUkGALZwAzhHxUmLChgDuWDjJay0KPgEF5KOMAgUcAJQjBWSLHnCT4yNJlx4qAbQDk7VwF0q01bwFCohI4ZJTSAL4MDADG2GLAUKJ26Nh8tqgpWLSMqihiIFjRbJxc9CqqUEim5lnOAIwANFAATE0AzJ7l4Q3leQVFcoocFOqlORXMI8AoAHQAZhhIAKIo0QAWHBxYrMKlhDSxWGIYADYQMycYCFs7XFwA3F0M4UA)

Comment: `down(data: Awaited<ReturnType<Migration<T>["up"]>>): Promise<void>` could be a step forward

Comment: I've added a [link to a TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsglgcwE4ENhwPYDsA8AVKAXigDcM4ATAPiKgG8AoKZqAVzAAoBKALigAUkGALZwAzhHxUmLChgDuWDjJay0KPgEF5KOMAgUcAJQjBWSLHnCT4yNJlx4qAbQDk7VwF0q01bwFCohI4ZJTSAL4MDADG2GLAUKJ26Nh8tqgpWLSMqihiIFjRbJxc9CqqUEim5lnOAIwANFAATE0AzJ7l4Q3leQVFcoocFOqlORXMI8AoAHQAZhhIAKIo0QAWHBxYrMKlhDSxWGIYADYQMycYCFs7XFwA3F0M4UA), and unfortunately I couldn't make your suggestion work

Answer (score 1):

you could use a create function that can infer the type, e.g.

```js
type Migration<T> = {
    up(): Promise<T>
    down(
        data: Awaited<ReturnType<Migration<T>['up']>>
    ): Promise<void>
}

function createMigration<T>(mig: Migration<T>) {
    return mig;
}

const migration = createMigration({
    async up() {
        return [1, 2, 3]
    },
    async down(data) {
        data.forEach((num) => console.log(num));
    }
})
```

[Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsglgcwE4ENhwPYDsA8AVAPigF4oBvAKCmqgFcwAKASgC4oAFJDAWzgGcI%20AlRoATDAHcsDETTFoUbAIISUcYBFE4AShGC0kWPOEHxkaTLkIBtAOT1bAXQLC5rDl14CcANwxxRYQBfCgoAM1osAGN0bCgopAg0CDNUWKsCBl4ENlSLbCEmclkoRP1DKGyAbgoQiijsPmBKxDTLEnjE5Lz0hko5FD4QaLpGIv65GjKDLChrAEYAGigAJmWAZkcSoMWSweGoqHEpBlEFcZK5M%20AUADowjCQAURQogAsGBixabiLiIgaWD4GAANhBbiCMAgvj8mEwanIQkEmEA)

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like the only way to achieve this is using factory with generic paramert. Here's an example:

```
type Migration<T> = {
  up(): Promise<T>;
  down(data: T): Promise<void>
}


const createMigration = <T,>(config: Migration<T>) => config

const myMigration = createMigration({
  async up() {
    return [1,2,3]
  },
  async down(data) {
    // data is infered from the `up` method
  }
})
```